# sql subquery returns unspecified error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, subquery

AM querying an access database from vb6 using the following query

```
INSERT INTO stock([i_name],[ref],[qty],[supplier_id]) 
VALUES('dd','dddd','11',(SELECT id FROM suppliers WHERE s_name ='dangote'))
```

but i get the following error when i run the query

```
-2147467259   Unspecified error           Microsoft JET Database Engine
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO stock([i_name],[ref],[qty],[supplier_id]) 
SELECT 'dd','dddd','11',id FROM suppliers WHERE s_name ='dangote';
```

That looks to me like it should work.  If you get an error, try pasting it into SQL View of a new query in Access.

If the field type of qty is numeric rather than text, discard the quotes around the value 11.

```
INSERT INTO stock([i_name],[ref],[qty],[supplier_id]) 
SELECT 'dd','dddd',11,id FROM suppliers WHERE s_name ='dangote';
```

Comment: Based on experience with SELECT statements ... `SELECT Now() AS snapshot_time, col1, col2 FROM Table1;`

Comment: how did you get this experience, you got the error some time ago? is there any other way around this?

Comment: I started using SQL in 1987.  I never attempted what you tried, so haven't gotten that same error.  With Access' db engine, I think INSERT ... VALUES lets you insert only one row of values.  INSERT ... SELECT will allow you to insert many.

Comment: wow, that's a long time ago. so which book. website, ref do you suggest i use to brush up my skills?

Comment: I've heard favorable comments about Joe Celko's SQL for Smarties.  Think I would look there first if I were starting today.  You can purchase a dead tree version, and I think it may also be available as a downloadable PDF for free.  Look around.  Good luck.

Comment: I read a review of that book today.  Its "intended audience is SQL programmers with at least a year's experience".  I didn't realize that.  It may not be what you want after all.